# Writing mutiple csv files into multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, csv

I tried to write multiple csv files with the same amount of columns and rows into multiple data frames, which can be accessed in a way like this:

```
file[1] #Outputs the whole content of the first csv file
file[2] #Outputs the whole content of the second csv file
```

and so on...

I have already saved everything into one data frame, but the neccesary values can't be accessed in such a way:

```
files = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
```

myfiles is one big data frame but I want to access them in the way I explained above.

I am using RStudio 0.9 and my working directory is where all files are located. The csv files are named in that way:
"001.csv"
"002.csv" "003.csv"...

Thank you in advance

Comment: What if you just change it to `myfiles = lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))` and then use `myfiles[[1]]` etc to access the elements?

Comment: This helped me, thank you :)

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, I believe you want the [assign](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html) function.  You could then use a for-loop to loop through each of your csv files, pushing each of them to their own uniquely-named R data frames.